# Casting child controls given the name as a string

Tags: vb.net

I want to cast a control given the name as a string, but it only works for controls directly on the form, and not for child controls (for any container).

```
    Dim LabelName As String = lb_TabControlTest.Name
    Dim l = DirectCast(Controls(LabelName), Label)
    If Not l Is Nothing Then
        lb_TabControlTestResult.Text = "Success"
    Else
        lb_TabControlTestResult.Text = "Failure"
    End If
```

Returns "Failure"

Can someone explain why this is/ if there is a better way to get around the issue than searching through every control in the parent until I find one with a matching name?

Comment: You need to specify the `Controls` collection of the direct parent. If you specify the `Controls` collection of the form then you only get controls for which the form is the direct parent.

Comment: If you don't know what the direct parent will be then you can write a recursive method to test every control's `Controls` collection.

Comment: By the way, you should be using `TryCast` there rather than `DirectCast`.  If there was a control with the specified name that was not a `Label` then that code would crash.

Comment: you mean like: Dim l = DirectCast(Controls("TabControl1.TabPage1." + LabelName), Label) ? assuming that the label name is correct.

Comment: No, I mean `TabPage1.Controls(LabelName)`, i.e. the `Controls` collection of the parent control, like I said.

Comment: @c3f - Start by creating a recursive function that traverses all of the controls on your form. Once you have that (which is pretty easy) then it's easy to find your control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Dim l = DirectCast(Controls(LabelName), Label)
```

to

```
Dim l = DirectCast(TabPage1.Controls(LabelName), Label)
```